# Conversion of programmatic UIView subclass to Nib-based UIView shows severe performance degradation

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I'm building an App, that shows a lot (100-500) of small views in some scrollpanel.
These views have several images, text labels, etc.
Now I wanted to have more declarative and intuitive designer of the views and switched to UI Builder (xib/nib).
But now I experience 4x-10x slower performance on opening the scene.
I already recognized, that if I e.g. disable Auto Layout option for the UIView, loading is accelerated at least twice. But still far slower, than what I did before programmatically.
I can just guess, that using Auto Layout with constraints is making everything to be calculated on each instantiation.
Does anyone have a tip, how to identify a bottleneck(s)?

Comment: How to identify a bottleneck: use Instruments.

Comment: Why dont u change to collection view altogether. That'd be best solution.

Comment: @Willeke, is it possible for you to elaborate a bit farther? What Instruments would you recommend to identify what exactly makes IB-solution slower?
Typically you'd see e.g. in performance reports that a view took so much time for the instantiation, but how to recognize that e.g. 'auto-layout' is the bottleneck or that particular constraint is worse than other?

Comment: Thanks, @GeneCode, didn't know about this option (still learning after couple years of hobby programming with Obj-C). Not sure if it fits my needs - i have very dynamic nature of the layout for the views, but I'll give a try to investigate it.
I'm speaking of this app, in case you're interested to see my challenge: https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/linkem/id896667794?mt=8

Comment: I checked out ur app and i think you might be rendering all the "cards" right? If so, You need to change the approach so that u only draw card that appear in the window visible to user only. this is the basic operation of tableview and collectionview- they implement some sort of reusable cells method. That way the ios is not burdened by the rendering of everything

Comment: Instruments quick start: In Xcode, choose Profile instead of Run. Instruments will start, choose Time Profiler. Hit the record button. Use the app. Stop recording. Explore. [Instruments User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH3-SW1).

Comment: @Willeke, I'm sorry, I'm using Time Profiler often, but I don't understand what you advice. How would you identify why instantiation of view takes specific time? It's just one line of code at the end.
Do you go deeper to the system calls to understand impacts of different XIB settings?

Comment: What is the bottleneck, loading the views from the nib or autolayout?

Comment: @Willeke, I've tried to explain it in my question, sorry, if it wasn't clear. I did conversion from programmatic UIView instantiation to defining the view in XIB and using UINib nibWithNibName/instantiateWithOwner.
And the views are loaded up to 10 times slower.
I asked what in the NIB definition may have so great impact on performance, that instantiation of it is slower, than I do programmatically?
As one of the examples of the bottlenecks, I already identified - if I switch off "Auto Layout" in the XIB, the views loaded "only" 5 times slower. What else could be the [biggest] bottlenecks?

Comment: I look at the cocoa methods. Usually I can recognize loading from XIB, autolayout, drawing and other things I didn't expect.